# Channel listing in irssi

Tags: irssi

So if you do /list, you end up with a list of every single channel on an irc server and it is difficult to read through. In a program like pidgin, it will give you a nice-looking list of channels and rank them by the most popular. Is there a way to do this in irssi or somehow else get a representation of channels that are readable?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of networks supports a channel listing service. On Freenode, for example, you can try `alis`.

Try:

`/msg alis help list`.

But sadly, there's no way to get this output out in a nice manner with Irssi.

Comment: It is unwork for me